# Get 5 rows from table

Tags: php, sql

I want to fetch 5 rows from table whose "lat" value is nearest to 30. I am developing Google MAP app, where i need the 5 nearest location from Data Base.
My table looks like that,

[image]

Comment: `ORDER BY ABS(lat - 30) ASC LIMIT 5`

Comment: @Paul you are great , make you comment as answer i will accept it

Comment: Which dbms? LIMIT is product specific...

Comment: On a map "nearest location" should be based on the distance of two points, otherwise `lat 30.00, long 75.00` will be the "nearest" location.

Comment: @dnoeth so can you tell me how to accomplish this task, i have the above table and i want to get 5 location nearest to me compare to my location latitude and longitude

Answer (score 5):

MySQL provides a Math function that turns negative numbers into absolute values. By using that, you can get the five closest locations whether their lat is slightly lower or higher than 30:

```
ORDER BY ABS(lat - 30) ASC LIMIT 5
```

The `ASC` is optional as it is the default sorting order in all DBMS (thanks Gordon).

Comment: . . `ASC` is the default in all databases.

Answer (score 1):

On a map "nearest location" should be based on the distance of two points, otherwise **lat 30.00, long 75.00** will be the "nearest" location.

A quite exact calculation of the distance between two points (latitude/longitude) is based on the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula):

```
DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(ref_latitude)) *
             COS(RADIANS(latitude)) *
             COS(RADIANS(ref_longitude) - RADIANS(longitude)) +
             SIN(RADIANS(ref_latitude)) *
             SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance

latitude = `lat`
longitude = `long`
ref_latitude & ref_longitude = the point you want to find the nearest locations from
`DOUBLE` should be used for calculation
```

This results in degrees, multiply by **111.195** for an approximate distance in kilometers or by **69.093** for miles.

As you want near locations you might go for a more simple calculation using the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

```
sqrt(power(lat-ref_latitude, 2) + 
     power((lng-ref_longitude)*cos(radians(ref_latitude)), 2))
```

Again multiply by **111.195** for kilometers or by **69.093** for miles.

Now simply `ORDER BY` this distance.

And instead of comparing to all rows in your database you should restrict the number of rows to compare, e.g.

```
WHERE latitude BETWEEN ref_latitude - 0.2 and ref_latitude + 0.2
  AND longitude BETWEEN ref_longitude - 0.2 and ref_longitude + 0.2
```

Btw, some DBMSes support geospatial extensions like `distance` functions or geospatial indexes.

Comment: Now i want to get the 5 nearest location, i have the location lat, long in data base and i want to compare its distance from my current location. how should i accomplish this task, should i fetch all the lat, long from data base, and after that i would calculate the distance and then show the 5 nearest location

Comment: @PirFahimShah: `ORDER BY distance LIMIT 5` or whatever syntax is supported by you DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, if you want to do this efficiently and you have an index on `lat`, then the following more complex query should perform better:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.*
       from table t
       where lat <= 30
       order by lat desc
       limit 5
      ) union all
      (select t.*
       from table t
       where lat > 30
       order by lat asc
       limit 5
      )
     ) t
order by abs(lat - 30)
limit 5;
```

The two subqueries can use an index on `lat` to avoid sorting.  The outer query is then only sorting 10 rows.